# In swing, Is it possible to find the Width and Height properties of a JPanel within paintComponent()?

Tags: java, image, swing, resize

I'm trying to center an image I have placed within a JPanel. In my paintComponent(), I have these lines:

```
        int x = (this.getWidth() - pic.getWidth(null)) / 2;
        int y = (this.getHeight() - pic.getHeight(null)) / 2;
        g2.drawImage(pic, x, y, null);
```

However, the image is still not center aligned. I printed out this.getWidth() and this.getHeight() and this gives me the dimensions of the image itself, rather than the JPanel.

The ideal solution would be:

```
        int x = (JPANEL.GETWIDTH() - pic.getWidth(null)) / 2;
        int y = (JPANEL.GETHEIGHT() - pic.getHeight(null)) / 2;
        g2.drawImage(pic, x, y, null);
```

But my issue that I do not have access to the JPanel's width and height since those properties are in another class.

I tried to make instance variables that saved and set the JPanel's width and height which worked. However, when I resize the window, it uses the JPanel's original width and height. I don't know how to update the code to adjust to the new JPanel's size when resizing the window. Any ideas?

Comment: My output is this:

width using this: 600, actual width of JPanel: 702
height using this: 400, actual height of JPanel: 540

Comment: I also set a preferred size and minimum size on the jpanel if that affects anything..

Comment: Those comments should be edited into the question. Look for the `edit` link below the question tags.

Answer (score 1):

> I printed out this.getWidth() and this.getHeight() and this gives me the dimensions of the image itself, rather than the JPanel.

No, those methods give the width/height of the panel not the image (unless you have custom code that does this).

For example you can use the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which allows you to center an image (among other things).

Note an easy way to center an image is to create a panel using a `GridBagLayout`. Then you create a JLabel with an ImageIcon and add the label to the panel. By default the component will be centered.

Maybe the image is not loaded when the painting method is invoked.

```
g2.drawImage(pic, x, y, null);
```

The above should be:

```
g2.drawImage(pic, x, y, this);
```

The "this" will make sure the component gets repainted as the image is loaded.

If you need more help with your custom painting code then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

> I also set a preferred size and minimum size on the jpanel if that affects anything..

You should NOT set a preferred size. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the preferred size.

When doing custom painting you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel to return the size of your image. But then the painting code will still need to calculated the image location to handle situations where the panel size is different than the preferred size.